# How can I center 3 divs and make it wrap to next line?

Tags: html, css

I have some recipe cards, and I want to make it so only 3 show on one line before it continues on the line below, and so that the container is centered to the page. Heres what I have:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
    <div class="recipe-container">
    <div class="recipe-window">
    <a href="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/easy-millionaires-shortbread" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/08/millionaires-shortbread-52587dd.jpg?quality=90&webp=true&resize=300,272"></a>
    <p class="recipe-title">Millionare's Shortbread</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-window">
    <a href="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/classic-white-loaf" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/08/recipe-image-legacy-id-559666_11-b53071d.jpg?quality=90&webp=true&resize=300,272"></a>
    <p class="recipe-title">Classic White Loaf</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-window">
    <a href="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/classic-white-loaf" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/08/recipe-image-legacy-id-1043451_11-4713959.jpg?quality=90&webp=true&resize=300,272"></a>
    <p class="recipe-title">Ultimate Chocolate Cake</p>
    </div>
    </div>


.recipe-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.recipe-window {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: min-content;
}

.recipe-title {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Change `display: flex;` and add `justify-content: center;` for `.recipe-container` class

```
.recipe-container {
   ...
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
```

Comment: It wouldn't work since flex can't decide how many columns you want to make on the layout, but grid can.

Comment: @Jericho That's not entirely true: By setting the width of the flex items to a percentage value, e.g. `33%`, in combination with `flex-wrap: wrap`, you can tell flex how many items you want to have per line.

Comment: Yep, i added `flex-wrap: wrap`  . Thanks @majusebetter

Answer (score 0):

You need to use grid. Change the `display: grid;` and add `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;` so it will only generate 3 columns of grid. After that add `justify-content: center;` to center the div. The class would be like this:

```
.recipe-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
```